# git: rebase between init commit to specified commit

Tags: git, rebase

How do I rebase between commits:

Lets say I want to rebase between init and commit 3 (squash these commits together)

Lets say i have

```
commit 5
commit 4
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
commit init
```

If I do

```
git rebase -i commit 3
```

I get this:

```
pick commit 3
pick commit 4
pick commit 5
```

Then when i do

```
squash commit 3
pick commit 4
pick commit 5
```

And I execute the action, I get this:

```
commit 3
commit 2
commit 1
commit init
```

Instead of what i want.

How do I squash commit init<---->commit 3, instead of commit 3<----->commit 5

Thanks in advance.

Jenia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do

```
git rebase -i --root
```

Git will drop you into an editor with

```
pick commitinit
pick commit2
pick commit3
pick commit4
pick commit5
```

then just change it to

```
pick commitinit
squash commit2
squash commit3
pick commit4
pick commit5
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't get the result you suggested with the commands you showed as you should still have commits 4 and 5, in the end.  To squash them all together you'd have to replace their `pick`s with `squash`es, not just the one for commit 3.

In order to squash one commit into another in an interactive rebase, you must start the rebase from *before* the point you want squashed, so that the list looks like this:

```
pick commit 2
pick commit 3
pick commit 4
pick commit 5
```

Now you can replace `pick` with `squash` on the second line and have commits 2 and 3 be combined (into one new, different commit).  (Note that commits 4 and 5 will be copied to new, different commits as well, with the same changes but different parent IDs.)

If you want to squash commit 2 into commit 1 as well, you must step back even further.

Essentially, you must start the rebase from a point one *before* the point of interest.  If the point of interest is right at the start, this is a bit of a problem—so interactive rebase allows you to specify `--root`.